# How to debug Dualshock 4 Pairing

Tags: macos, usb, drivers, bluetooth

I'm not sure when this happened but all of a sudden I'm unable to pair my PS4 controller with my mac. I'm running 10.10, but I don't think it's a 10.10 problem since I was able to pair it instantly with another Mac.

Is there anyway on a Mac to see all bluetooth drivers or perhaps start some kind of debugging functionality so I can actually see the error?

**Update**: So I was actually able to trace this and reproduce the problem. It seems that plugging in my USB gaming mouse prevents the PS4 controller from pairing properly. Unplugging the mouse does not fix the problem. I assume this means that there are some USB drivers that I need to get rid of for the PS4 controller to work again.

**Update 2**: The mouse I was referencing earlier is the Logitech g700s, so I've been looking into ways to uninstall default mouse drivers. I've also installed Logitech's support software for the mouse but it didn't help.

My theory is that plugging in the mouse modified some kind of shared resource that the PS4 controller used as well, which is now preventing it from pairing/functioning.

**Update 3:** The USB mouse's dongle is a BRCM20702 Hub which is a bluetooth adapter. This makes more sense as the USB probably edited some default resource which in turn messed up the PS4 controller.

**Update 4:** Surprisingly enough I was able to pinpoint at around what time i had plugged the mouse in. I used Finder's search to see all files modified/created/added at around that time (I included system files within the search too). Sadly this doesn't show hidden files.

**Update 5:** I actually managed to search for hidden files as well, but nothing looked suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution by playing with Apple's bluetooth suite.  They have a service called Bluetooth explorer which lets you pair devices and it ended up working for me. The suite also has a lot of other useful tools.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action -- Hardware I/O tools

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as @Uri said, the Bluetooth Explorer is the solution for it.

1. Just access this link https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
2. Log in into your Apple account
3. Type "Bluetooth" into the search bar, download the `dmg` for the latest "Hardware I/O tools"
4. Open it up, select "Bluetooth Explorer", check your taskbar, and goto

   > Tools -> Controller/Stack Options -> Hardware Reset -> Re-enumerate USB Bluetooth module

   and click "Reset"

[Downloading the I/O Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZj9Z.jpg)
[Selecting the right option on Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al3GI.jpg)